# Como atualizar um datagridview automaticamente?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6, datagridview, ado.net

Criei um aplicativo que irá exibir os dados de uma determinada view num controle `datagridview`.
Toda a aplicação já está pronta: o carregamento dos dados, o botão para atualizar e também os eventos `load` e `activated`.

**Tecnologias utilizadas:**

- ADO.NET Entity Data Model
- EF 6.x EntityObject Generator
- SQL Server 2012

*Obs: Estou utilizando o BindingSource na propriedade DataSource do datagridview para carregar as informações.*

Segue abaixo o código da minha aplicação:

```
private void frmDados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CarregaDados();
}

private void CarregaDados()
{
    using (var context = new DadosEntities())
    {
        vGRUPOSBindingSource.DataSource = context.VGRUPOS.ToList();
    }
}

private void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CarregaDados();
}

/// <summary>
/// Evento acionado quando o foco retornar ao formulário
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void frmDados_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CarregaDados();
}
```

**Minha dúvida**

Como fazer para atualizar o controle `datagridview` automaticamente após qualquer alteração nos dados da tabela?

Seja diretamento pelo banco de dados ou por outro aplicativo aberto sendo alimentado por outros usuários.

O controle precisa ser atualizado sem qualquer influencia do usuário - ativando o foco na aplicação ou clicando no botão Atualizar.

**Cenário de exemplo**

Com minha aplicação aberta, definida como um **painel informativo** são exibidas as informações sobre o estoque de produtos. A medida que por **outro aplicativo** um controle de estoque (em WinForm, Mobile ou WEB), dá entradas ou saídas, o meu aplicativo painel informativo precisa mostrar as novas informações.

Pode acontecer também de uma operação em lote, atualizar o estoque de muitos produtos via banco de dados, ou seja, um `update` diretamente pelo `SQL`, sendo assim, o meu painel informativo precisa atualizar em tempo real as informações no `datagridview`.

Comment: Winform ou WPF? Conhece DataBinding?

Comment: Estou utilizando winform. O DataBinding já utilizei no wpf.

Answer (score 1):

Com [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) (`System.ComponentModel.BindingList`) eu consegui esse efeito de atualizar um dado e logo atualizar o DataGridView. A única coisa chata é ter que adicionar o novo item no [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) para ter o efeito, não é tão automático, mas, isso me livra de ficar carregando os dados novamente da base de dados para *DataGridView*.

Crie um `ViewModel` como no código logo abaixo, implementando a *interface* [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class PessoaViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _nome;

    public int Id {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id"));
            }
        }
    }
    public string Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return _nome;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_nome != value)
            {
                _nome = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Nome"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

No formulário crie um propriedade:

```
protected BindingList<PessoaViewModel> PessoasBindingList;
```

e no Load do Form faça o seu carregamento:

```
PessoasBindingList = new BindingList<PessoaViewModel>(
    Database.Pessoas.Select(c => new PessoaViewModel
{
    Id = c.Id,
    Nome = c.Nome
}).ToList());

DataGridViewPessoas.DataSource = PessoasBindingList;
DataGridViewPessoas.Update();
DataGridViewPessoas.Refresh();
Update();
```

Quanto incluir algum item na sua base de dados, deve-se incluir também na propriedade criada `PessoasBindingList`

Exemplo:

***Insert***

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
p.Nome = TxtNome.Text;
Database.Pessoas.Add(p);
Database.SaveChanges();
PessoasBindingList.Add(new PessoaViewModel()
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Nome = p.Nome
});
```

***Update***

```
int Id = int.Parse(TxtId.Text);
Pessoa p = Database.Pessoas.Find(Id);
p.Nome = TxtNome.Text;
Database.Entry(p).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
Database.SaveChanges();
PessoasBindingList
    .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Nome = TxtNome.Text;
```

Se for excluir é da mesma forma exclui da base e depois do [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: João, obrigado pela resposta, no entanto, após a implementação desta técnica, estarei na mesma situação: o DataGridView não é atualizado automaticamente até novamente eu busque do banco as novas informações. Inclui em minha pergunta um cenário de exemplo.

Comment: @ismael agora eu entendi seu processo lógico de desenvolvimento, realmente essa solução funcionaria se a mesma variável tivesse acesso a outras telas, e assim funcionaria do jeito que tu pediu. Mas, você poderia então usar WPF nessa tela então, é a única maneira prática de se fazer algo assim. Poderia também criar um timer de tempos em tempos atualizava essa tela, também funcionaria com essa base que você já tem. Realmente WPF é a solução viável, ou seja, Windows Forms para isso realmente não dá o efeito esperado !!! Só uma dica em novas perguntas, sempre coloque o cenário isso ajuda e muito!

Comment: @ismael apesar dessa solução não servir para você, ela é funciona se você for utilizar na mesma tela as mesmas variaveis... O Binding acontece

Comment: Sim João, na mesma janela sim.